# Shorthand for else if statment in PHP

Tags: php

I know there is a shorthand for IF/ELSE STATEMENT in PHP such as

```
($user['permissions'] == 'admin' ? true : false);
```

But is there a shorthand for ELSE IF statement besides switch?

Comment: Yes, you can chain ternary operators together; don't tell anyone I told you this though ;-)

Comment: @Jack =oO I'm telling!

Comment: It's not a shorthand it's a separate operator

Comment: only do this if you are entering a code obfustication contest.

Comment: Why is this closed as NC? I see no reason for doing so, the question has a pretty clear Yes/No answer, albeit with a big But on the Yes :) voting to reopen.

Answer (score 3):

**What you could do**

You can keep chaining ternary operators together, e.g.:

```
$x = $condition1 ? true : ($condition2 ? true : false);
```

It looks nice now, but once your conditions grow bigger, it quickly becomes unreadable. Note that parentheses are bare essentials for these kind of expressions.

**What you should do**

Once you add more conditions, prefer to use the proper branching syntax; always assume the person who later has to take over your code is a psychopath who knows where you live:

```
$canAccess = false;
if ($user['permissions'] == 'admin') {
    $canAccess = true;
} elseif ($user['permissions'] == 'whatever') {
    $canAccess = true;
}
```

*Yes, you could use an `or` in the first statement too.*

Or, a switch:

```
switch ($user['permissions']) {
    case 'admin':
    case 'whatever':
        $canAccess = true;
        break;

    default:
        $canAccess = false;
}
```

Comment: Does not answer the question. The question was "shorthand for else if", not "why non-shorthand is better". This would have been better as a comment on one of the ternary op answers.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Ever heard of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? a "you're doing it wrong" answer is also an answer.

Comment: I have. I have also heard of the "off-topic" problem. What I am not saying is that your answer is completely wrong (it isn't) - it just fails to address the main question of the OP. He wanted a shorthand - the best kind of answer is "yes, there is a shorthand but it is a nightmare to read, here's why". Providing the second half of this does not answer the OP's question, and would have been more appropriate in comment.

Comment: @SébastienRenauld Let's be clear first that what OP wants and needs are two different things. But sure, I'll add some more detail to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

I’d rather just use `elseif() {}` anyway

```
$somevalue == 'foo' ? 'is foo' : ($somevalue == 'bar' ? 'is bar' : 'is neither');
```